# What's the cleanest way to turn an object into a list without using a double for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have an object called 'times', that holds another object called '20102', that holds a list of 3 objects. It looks like this:

```
times: {
    20102: [
        { name:'jane', age:12 },
        { name:'josh', age:19 },
        { name:'jill', age:14 },
    ]
}
```

However, what I want it to look like is this:

```
times:[
    { name:'jane', age:12 },
    { name:'josh', age:19 },
    { name:'jill', age:14},
]
```

I was thinking of doing a double for loop but that's not efficient. What's a better way?

Comment: code makes no sense, it is full of syntax errors

Comment: If you have a structure that is nested two layers deep, you **need** two nested loops. It is the most efficient (linear) approach to visit all items. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @epascarello sorry, fixing.

Comment: So you remove the keys and changed it to numbers.... why do you have the 0: in the array?

Comment: times:[
{key:value},
{key:value},
{key:value},
] do you need it like this?

Comment: `[0:{` is still not a valid syntax.

Comment: @epascarello I was showing the indices like how it appears in the console.

Comment: @lost_in_magento yes. Possible without a double loop?

Comment: Just show the actual object code who a developer would write it so one could copy and paste it and write an answer.

Comment: Is it dynamic? meaning it can have multiple objects or no objects

Comment: The question still seems incomplete. In the current form you could just write. `obj.times = obj.times['20102']`. Please extend the example and the description of you problem to make clearer what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like you could just do `times = times["20102"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Object.values() and flat()

```js
var x = {
  times: {
    20102: [{
        'key': '1'
      },
      {
        'key': '2'
      },
      {
        'key': '3'
      },
    ]
  }
};
x.times = Object.values(x.times).flat();

console.log(x);
```

If you know there will only be one key

```js
var x = {
  times: {
    20102: [{
        'key': '1'
      },
      {
        'key': '2'
      },
      {
        'key': '3'
      },
    ]
  }
};
x.times = Object.values(x.times)[0];

console.log(x);
```

Comment: You have double loop here

Comment: Unless the OP knows the key[s], there is going to be two loops.

Comment: @epascarello yea, I can't hardcode the keys so this makes sense.